# Show that $E(Z)=E(K)E(X)$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

Let ${X_n, n\in N}$ be an iid sequence of psitive rrvs and let $K$ be a rrv independent of this sequence and taking its values in $N$ with $P(K=k)=p_k$. Consider the rrv $Z=\sum_{n=1}^{K} X_n$. Suppose that $E(X_n) <\infty$. Then show $E(Z)=E(K)E(X_n)$

My attempt is that since $K$ is independent of $X_n$ then how can i apply independence formula for expectation?

Answer (score 2):

$EZ=\sum_k E(Z|K=k)P(K=k)$ $=\sum_k  (kEX_1) P(K=k)=E(X_1) \sum_k kP(Z=k)=EX_1EK$.  Note that $EX_n$ doe not depend on $n$ since $(X_I)$ is i.i.d..

Comment: So this is for $n=1$ right? Then can we generalize it for $X_n$?

Comment: @yorukobasi See my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
Z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_nI(K\geq n).
$$
Since the $X_n$ are non-negative the monotone convergence theorem together with independence of $X_n$ and $K$ imply that
$$
EZ=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (EX_n)P(K\geq n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty EX_1 P(K\geq n)=EX_1\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(K\geq n)=EX_1 EK
$$
where in the final step we use the tail formula for expectation.